# Trying to learn how to use template

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

#define M 6
#define N 5

template <class T>
T *merge(T *a, T *b) {
  T *c = new int[N+M];
  for (int i=0, j=0, k=0; k<N+M; k++)
    if (j>=M || (i<N && a[i] < b[j])) c[k] = a[i++];
    else                              c[k] = b[j++];
  return c;
}

int main() {
  int  a[N] = {3, 2, 5, 11, 7};
  char b[M] = {'i', 's', 'b', 'y', 'o', 'p'};
  int *c   = merge(a, b);
  for (int i=0; i<N+M; i++)
    std::cout << c[i] << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile the code, it gives me "sort.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘merge(int [5], char [6])’". Can someone explain what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Use constants not macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `merge(a,b)`, the compiler tries to deduce the type `T` given the arguments `a` and `b`. `a` decays to `int*` and `b` decays to `char*`. `b` has to be converted to `int*` for the type deduction to result in `T = int` or `a` has to be converted to `char*` for the deduction to result in `T = char`. Since neither of those are valid conversions, the compiler cannot deduce `T`.

You can resolve the problem by making `b` an array of `int`s or by making `a` an array of `char`s.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain what I did wrong?

Well, I won't say that you're not supposed to merge a list of integers and a list of characters because you could do that if you really wanted (for learning purposes maybe?)

So @R Sahu answer is correct in the sense that you're mixing types that are not implicitly convertible. Still, that's may not be the answer you wanted. Instead of why is *this wrong use of that template*, you want to know why is this *template wrong to this use*.

What you did wrong (supposing that you want to mix types) was to declare you template with only one `typename`, hence forcing both arguments to be the same type:

`template <class T> T *merge(T *a, T *b)`

You see, `a` and `b` are both pointers of type `T`, which is not possible because `char*` and `int*` are not compatible. You would need two typenames to accommodate you use:

`template <class T, class U> T *merge(T *a, U *b)`

And that's exactly what the compile error message tells you: you have two types, but no template can match that.